# Kernel panic from GNU GRUB after updating from 18.04.6 to 20.04.6 even from 3 recovery mode options

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, grub2, kernel, do-release-upgrade

Updated from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. Got the following error:

```
A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of network problem, please check your network connection and retry. E:Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh-cache > /dev/null; fi', E:Sub-process returned an error code
```

I also saw some errors relating to:

```
appstreamcli: symbol lookup error: appstreamcli: undefined symbol: AS_APPSTREAM_METADATA_PATHS
```

Came back the next day and could log in fine to the machine; even said it was running Ubuntu 20.04.6. Tried "sudo apt update" and got the error:

```
sudo: pam_open_session: module is unknown
```

Did a reboot, and now the computer only goes to the GNU GRUB loader and all 6 options (3 of which are recovery) in the "Advanced Options" result in:

```
"end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init".
```

Making a bootable USB drive now. Are there any options I have that won't result in wiping out all files? Thankfully the important files were backed up to some mounted harddrives; however, there are still some files in home directories that would be great to recover.